# Altium count number of selected vias

Tags: altium, via

Is there a way in Altium to count the number of selected vias? For example, the below figure shows 9 vias, which are manually countable. In some layouts where I have a lot more than that, how should I keep track of the number of vias?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the PCB panel (View > PCB), you can select "Pad & Via Templates" from the menu at top and are presented with a list of every via type (template) used in the PCB, which includes the counts for each:

[image: PCB Panel, Pad & Via Templates]

Selecting any of the listed templates will select/highlight those vias for you to verify.

Alternatively, if you select only the objects you are interested in, there is a count for the number of selected objects at the bottom of the Properties panel:

[image: Properties panel with selected object count]

Finally, if your reason for counting vias is for drilling purposes or cost estimation, know that there is a drill table which your PCB fabricator will usually request. The drill table lists all drill hits (holes) with their dimensions. You can place a drill table (usually somewhere off-board, and usually on a mechanical or "drill guide" layer) by selecting Place > Drill Table from the menu. Here is an example:

[image: Drill table example]

Comment: thanks very much !!!

Answer (score 1):

After selecting the objects in Altium, open the Properties panel. At the very bottom edge it will tell you how many objects are selected.

[image]